# Javascript clone() is not a function error

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

Im working on a js game, and trying to clone an object, but I keep having this error :

`this[i].clone is not a function`

this is my code :

```js
Object.prototype.clone = function() {
    var i, newObj = (this instanceof Array) ? [] : {};
    for (i in this) {
        if (i === 'clone') {
            continue;
        }
        if (this[i] && typeof this[i] === "object") {
            newObj[i] = this[i].clone();
        } else {
            newObj[i] = this[i];
        }
    }
    return newObj;
};
```

I tried to remplace 'clone' with this solution :

`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))` 
it didn't work. any help please ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)

Comment: Can you provide a example of how you're using this code as a [mcve] and add it to the question?

Comment: `Object.prototype.clone =`  Just a heads up, modifying built in prototypes is not a great idea, unless polyfilling.

Comment: What is the problem with `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks as it works

```js
Object.prototype.clone = function() {
    var i, newObj = (this instanceof Array) ? [] : {};
    for (i in this) {
        if (i === 'clone') {
            continue;
        }
        if (this[i] && typeof this[i] === "object") {
            newObj[i] = this[i].clone();
        } else {
            newObj[i] = this[i];
        }
    }
    return newObj;
};

var person = {
    name: 'John',
    address: {
        city: 'New York'
    }
};

var clonedPerson = person.clone();

person.address.city = 'Buenos Aires';

console.log(person.address.city);
console.log(clonedPerson.address.city);
```

What is your call look like?

Comment: Thank you for your response ! this is me error message : `[Vue warn]: Error in getter for watcher "clone": "TypeError: this[i].clone is not a function" `

Comment: Please paste the code that calls the clone with the error. You can also try to add some `console.log(this[i]);` before `newObj[i] = this[i].clone();` line to figure out which property makes the problem.